# Calculated Value - Date time problem

Tags: calculated-column-formula

The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

I get this error and I tried this formulas:
`=TEXT([LeavingTime]-[ArrivingTime],"h") 
=DATEDIF([ArrivingTime], [LeavingTime],"d")`

where ArrivingTime, LeavingTime and TimeSpend are Date time columns
Which regional settings should I use or is there any other problem?

Comment: Is using a workflow an Option?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the **,** is not the parameter separator in your language.

Just like with Excel you have to use the **;** for most non-english languages